# spark local mode and standalone mode on single server/machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a single server of 24 cores and 260 gb. Is using spark on local mode better option here or using standalone cluster mode is better to use here for speed?

and what if on same server, I make 4 different containers and assign 6 cores and 65 gb to each and then use standalone cluster manager. Will this increase performance?

Will performance remain same in all these scenarios? which one is better for a single machine.

I have used local mode but not standalone mode yet.

Comment: You could even use YARN or Mesos in that case. As you have a single machine, I guess adding a Cluster Manager in the middle won't  produce any benefit. At the end of the day, why would you want a cluster manager to control a single machine? In deed, there are probably better options out there for a single machine like [polars](https://www.pola.rs/), depending on your transformations and workload.